# Google App Engine SSL and Unique IP

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

My domain is hosted by Dreamhost. My app engine app is served by a custom domain, but is a sub-domain: app.example.com. My app is not accessed by a browser, but requests are made from an iOS app.

Now, I've purchased a basic SSL certificate from Dreamhost specifically for the subdomain app.example.com.

Next, I've uploaded the necessary crt and pem files to Google Domain Settings, and everything went ok with that. The domain settings do show that the upload was successful, and I have assigned the CNAME to ghs.googlehosted.com.

At this point, I'm not exactly sure what to do. Am I to expect SSL to just magically be enabled by this point? Because it still doesn't look like it has been.

What's confusing me is this talk about SNI and unique IPs. Dreamhost says, aside from GAE, that I'd need a unique IP to host my certificate. I'm not sure though if that's just a Dreamhost thing, or I really do need that. If so, do I need a unique IP for the subdomain separate from the main domain?

Or is this what SNI takes care of? What exactly should I be doing at this point?

Comment: Is it possible to use Google's SSL functionality and simply point to app.appspot.com?  That would get rid of the need for setting up SSL yourself.

Comment: @MichaelDavis ya but I don't want to use appspot..

Comment: Did you follow these instructions?  Are you already serving from your own domain?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand what SNI is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Then you should follow the config docs for [SSL on custom domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl).

Btw, iOS since v4 supports SNI so you should be OK.

Update: if you want unique IP, then you should use VIP. But this costs extra and is not necessary in your case as iOS supports SNI. VIP is only needed for some older browsers.